# On "The Power of the Prover" in Arora and Barak

Tags: interactive-proofs

In section 8.4 of [Arora and Barak](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521424267), after describing the public coin protocol for $\mathsf{GNI}$ and $\mathrm{IP=PSPACE}$, the authors state:

> A curious feature of many known interactive proof systems is that in order to prove membership in language $L$ the prover needs to do more powerful computation than just deciding membership in $L$.  We give some examples.
>
> 1. The public coin system for graph nonisomorphism in Theorem 8.13 requires the prover to produce, for some randomly chosen hash function $h$ and a random element $y$ in the range of $h$, a graph $H$ **such that $h(H)$ is isomorphic to either $G_1$ or $G_2$ and $h(x)=y$.** This seems harder than just solving graph non-isomorphism (though we do not know of any proof that it is).

I believe the intent was:

> ...a graph $H$ such that $H$ is isomorphic to either $G_1$or $G_2$ and $h(H)=y$...

although I can't find it in any errata.

But more importantly, I believe the comment was to the effect of "finding preimages of hashes can be challenging, and the only obvious way for Merlin to execute the public coin $\mathsf{GNI}$ protocol is to go through each and every permutation $\pi$ of $G_1$ or $G_2$ and calculate $h(\pi(G_i))$ until he finds an $h(\pi(G_i))=y$."

But is it the case that all such public-coin protocols put a heavy burden on the prover?  For example, the hash $h$ is not *required* to be difficult to invert; it just needs to be strongly universal, which, as I understand, is not the same as being one-way.  So if Arthur were to give Merlin an image $y$ for some "easy-to-invert" hash function $h$, then it might not be so difficult for Merlin to find the preimage.

> Is that the right interpretation of Arora and Barak?  Has there been any progress on Arora and Barak's statement?

Answers to [this question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2461/interactive-proofs-for-levels-of-the-polynomial-hierarchy) suggests that it is an open question as to whether an interactive proof for a problem in $\mathrm{coNP}$ requires the prover to do as much work as a $\mathrm{\#P}$ machine.