# Does the MIP* = RE proof work for limited provers?

Tags: interactive-proofs

[MIP* = RE](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.04383) shows that two arbitrarily strong entangled provers can convince a verifier of instances of the halting problem.  Now assume that we have two entangled provers that are only capable of solving problems in some language $L$ (say a language complete for NEEXP, NEEEXP, etc.).

**Question**: What constraints on $L$ allow provers to convince a verifier of solutions to $L$?

The nonquantum analogy is that not only is IP = PSPACE, but IP' = PSPACE where IP' provers are only able to solve PSPACE level problems.  In particular, L = PSPACE works for the MIP* question.  <s>Moreover, provers that are limited to any level of the polynomial hierarchy $\Sigma_k \textrm{P}$ can establish $\Sigma_k \textrm{P} \subset \textrm{PSPACE}$.</s> (Unfortunately, looks like this doesn't work [lower in the polynomial hierarchy](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2461/interactive-proofs-for-levels-of-the-polynomial-hierarchy?rq=1).)

(I'm blurring over some definitional subtlety here about function problems vs. decision problems; in the above one probably needs the provers to be able to solve $\textrm{FP}^L$ rather than just L.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe our result shows that if the prover is capable of solving NTIME[poly(T)] problems, and has the ability to manipulate polylog(T) qubits, then they can convince the verifier of YES instances of NTIME[T] problems.

In other words, roughly speaking NTIME[2^poly(Q)] = MIP*[Q] where MIP*[Q] denotes the provers being limited to Q qubits of entanglement.

Comment: Thank you!  To clarify: your first statement seems much stronger than the second due to $T$ being the same in both occurrences of NTIME.  Would there be some blowup?

Comment: Yes there's some blow-up, it should be something like NTIME[poly(T)] provers can prove NTIME[T] languages.

Comment: Reasonable to conjecture that for suitably large $T$ the blowup disappears?

Comment: I think in our proof there is always some blow-up. It's a modest polynomial blow-up, but there nonetheless.