# Is there a version of MIP=NEXP with relatively efficient provers?

Tags: interactive-proofs

(My question is not a duplicate of [this question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/696/mip-with-efficient-provers).)

Fix a good coding of non-deterministic [random-access machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_machine).

For non-negative integers $m$ that code such a machine, let

$\operatorname{states}(m)$ denote the number of internal states in the coded machine.

("hc" stands for "hard-coded".)

Choose some polynomial function $hcpoly$, and let $L$ be the language

$\{\langle m\hspace{.02 in},\hspace{-0.025 in}t,\hspace{-0.02 in}s\hspace{-0.02 in}\rangle \;\; : \;\; m$ codes such a machine and $\:t\leq 2^{hcpoly(\operatorname{states}(m))}\:$ and

there is a sequence of non-deterministic choices which will make that machine

accept the empty string in at most $t$ time without using more than $s$ space$\}\;$.

> Is there a [MIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_proof_system#MIP) protocol for $L\hspace{.02 in}$ in which the provers use not
>   
>   much more than $t$ time and/or not much more than $s$ space?

That could just mean $\:poly(\hspace{.02 in}\operatorname{length}(\langle m\hspace{.02 in},\hspace{-0.025 in}t,\hspace{-0.02 in}s\hspace{-0.02 in}\rangle))\:$ time and space, although

ideally it would be $\:poly(\operatorname{states}(m))\hspace{-0.03 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.03 in}t\:$ time and $\:poly(\operatorname{states}(m))\hspace{-0.03 in}+\hspace{-0.03 in}s\:$ space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. ​ ​ ​ [This paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/461.pdf) constructs "a one-round succinct MIP of knowledge, where each prover runs in time $t\cdot \operatorname{polylog}(t)$ and space $s\cdot \operatorname{polylog}(t)$ and the verifier runs in time" ​ $\operatorname{length}(m) \cdot \operatorname{polylog}(t)$ .